# Symfony 4 API Platform Persist Child Issue?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I am unable to persist a collection when creating a new product.

Product Entity has OneToMany Relationship with ProductDetails.

Inside ProductDetails, I have ManyToOne with ColorList and SizeList Entities.

So ProductDetails holds, ProductID, ColorID, SizeID. Relationship works just fine but when I use API Platfrom to persist productDetils it does not work.

I create a EventSubscriber as well and intercept the request POST_DESERIALIZE the objects in POST request for ProductDetails disappear.

There is no error I am still getting 201 (Object Created).

Product Entity

```
    /**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={"get","post"},
 *     itemOperations={"get","put"},
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"product:read"}},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"product:write"}}
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProductRepository::class)
 */
class Product
{
    use TimestampableEntity;
    use SoftDeleteableEntity;
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Store::class, inversedBy="products")
     */
    private $store;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"product:read","product:write"})
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"product:read","product:write"})
     */
    private $barcode;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=ProductDetails::class, mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist"})
     * @Groups({"product:read","product:write"})
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $productDetails;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"product:read","product:write"})
     */
    private $sku;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"product:read","product:write"})
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"product:read","product:write"})
     */
    private $brand;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"product:read","product:write"})
     */
    private $productcondition;
```

Product Detail Entity

```
    class ProductDetails
{
    use TimestampableEntity;
    use SoftDeleteableEntity;
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Product::class, inversedBy="productDetails")
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"product_detail:read", "product_detail:write", "product:read", "product:write"})
     */
    private $quantity;

    /**
     * @ApiSubresource()
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=ColorList::class, inversedBy="productDetails")
     * @Groups({"product_detail:read", "product_detail:write", "product:read", "product:write"})
     */
    private $color;

    /**
     * @ApiSubresource()
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=SizeList::class, inversedBy="productDetails")
     * @Groups({"product_detail:read", "product_detail:write", "product:read", "product:write"})
     */
    private $size;
```

```
Getter & Setter (Update 1)

/**
  * @return Collection|ProductDetails[]
  */
    public function getProductDetails(): Collection
    {
        return $this->productDetails;
    }

    public function addProductDetails(ProductDetails $productDetails): self
    {
        if (!$this->productDetails->contains($productDetails)) {
            $this->productDetails[] = $productDetails;
            $productDetails->setProduct($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProductDetails(ProductDetails $productDetails): self
    {
        if ($this->productDetails->contains($productDetails)) {
            $this->productDetails->removeElement($productDetails);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($productDetails->getProduct() === $this) {
                $productDetails->setProduct(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

I am not sure why API is not mapping the collection, GET call works just fine.

Any help would be great.

Comment: can you show Product::addProductDetail / Product::setProductDetails please? In general, I would assume that the *product* on ProductDetail is not being set at all, since that field is not provided. if your add/set method doesn't set it either, adding will probably fail. however, an error message would have been nice (obv. not your fault).

Comment: thanks for reply, just updated question with Getter & Setter, as for error msg there is none.  as I have posted the response as well, 201 .. without any error. Symfony Profiler also says everything is good.

Comment: okay, I would switch to debugging and just check, if the add method is ever called (maybe `dd` inside the adder). because cascaded persist is set. I have not enough insight into api-platform to see the important details though.